# panel hide when collapse in extjs

Tags: forms, extjs, panel

I try to explain my problem. I have a tab panel. In one tab I have a form panel and a grid panel, both collapsable. When I collapse the form panel it will collapse, when I collapse the gridpanel both are collapsed. Now when I uncollapse one of the two panels the other one disappears. What could this be?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.TMS', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

    id: 'tmsViewport',
    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },

    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                id: 'mainTab',
                activeTab: 0,
                region: 'center',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    id: 'configurationTab',
                    title: 'Configuration',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'tabpanel',
                        id: 'configurationVehicles',
                        title: 'configuration',
                        activeTab: 0,
                        items: [{
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            id: 'configurationDrivers',
                            collapsed: false,
                            title: 'Drivers',
                            items: [{
                                xtype: 'form',
                                floating: false,
                                height: 400,
                                id: 'configurationDriversConfiguration',
                                itemId: 'configurationDriversConfiguration',
                                bodyPadding: 10,
                                animCollapse: false,
                                collapsed: false,
                                collapsible: true,
                                title: 'Driver Configuration',
                                items: [{
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    id: 'configurationDriversAdd',
                                    text: 'Add'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    id: 'configurationDriversDelete',
                                    text: 'Delete'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    id: 'configurationDriversCode',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Driver Code'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    id: 'configurationDriversName',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Driver Name'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    id: 'configurationDriversLicense',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Driver License nr'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    id: 'configurationDriversGivenName',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Driver Given Name'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    id: 'configurationDriversFamilyName',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Driver Familiy Name'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    id: 'configurationDriversPhone',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Driver Phone Nr'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'textfield',
                                    id: 'configurationDriversEmail',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Driver Email'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'combobox',
                                    id: 'configurationDriversProvider',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Provider',
                                    displayField: 'name',
                                    store: 'comboProviders',
                                    valueField: 'id'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'textareafield',
                                    id: 'configurationDriversMemo',
                                    fieldLabel: 'Memo'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'button',
                                    handler: function (button, event) {
                                        var form = document.forms;

                                        Ext.MessageBox.alert('Submitted Values', form.getValues(true));


                                    },
                                    height: 37,
                                    id: 'configurationDriversSave',
                                    text: 'Save'
                                }]
                            }, {
                                xtype: 'gridpanel',
                                height: 300,
                                id: 'configurationDriversGrid',
                                itemId: 'configurationDriversGrid',
                                animCollapse: false,
                                collapsible: true,
                                title: 'Drivers',
                                store: 'gridDrivers',
                                viewConfig: {

                                },
                                columns: [{
                                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                    dataIndex: 'id',
                                    text: 'Id'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                    dataIndex: 'version',
                                    text: 'Version'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                    dataIndex: 'driverId',
                                    text: 'DriverId'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                    dataIndex: 'firstName',
                                    text: 'FirstName'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                    dataIndex: 'middleName',
                                    text: 'MiddleName'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                    dataIndex: 'lastName',
                                    text: 'LastName'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                    dataIndex: 'email',
                                    text: 'Email'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                    dataIndex: 'workPhone',
                                    text: 'WorkPhone'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                    dataIndex: 'note',
                                    text: 'Note'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                    dataIndex: 'licenseNumber',
                                    text: 'LicenseNumber'
                                }, {
                                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                                    dataIndex: 'providerId',
                                    text: 'ProviderId'
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say anything without having a fiddle or some simpler sample, but looking at your code I noticed one interesting thing:

You have `layout: border` only on the top level and then you have many nested panels inside. Try to define `border` layout in the container that contains your two panels that are collapsing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use a border layout you may want to refer to this: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/layout/border.html  I've only ever used this for the east and west panels to hiding and showing additional information on an event trigger. Since you already have IDs it would probably be better to manually trigger those specifically.